# copy to clipboard with vim running in windows 10 cmd line window

Tags: vim, copy, paste, yank

I have a windows 10 PC.
The VIM session is run from a command prompt window.
Normally when I copy and paste, I do the following steps:

```
1. go into edit mode by typing ":"
2. select the text with mouse drag
3. right click on mouse button
4. move cursor to a text editor, which is a different window than the VIM terminal.
5. right click and select Paste.
```

How do I do that the same with yank?

I know there's a trick about using clipboard "*y, but I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: I can't tell you if it works for windows, but try using `"+y`

Answer (score 0):

Use the yank command. Select the text you want to copy and type `"*y`